# Authentication without redirection on a pure ReactJS app (SPA)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In a pure Single Page Application built using ReactJS where the server is just an API, is there a reason to redirect for logging in?

The usual workflow when you access a URL that you need to be logged in to access and you are not, is:

1. Redirect to /log_in with next_page attribute.
2. Log in.
3. Redirect back to next_page.

In a SPA using ReactJS, all the pages that need log in could easily be put inside a component that doesn't show the page and instead shows the log in dialog.

Are there any technical problems to this approach? Any security or usability problems?

Comment: When you say "redirect" do you mean a full page load or something like a `react-router` [`<Redirect>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) ?

Comment: @apokryfos: react-router  `<Redirect>` or a history push, so, not a full page load.

Comment: What you're describing then does look a lot like the first example in [the redirect docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) where the component that doesn't show the page but shows the login dialog instead is the `<Route>` component itself (if you changed the redirect to the actual login page).

Comment: @apokryfos: yeah, my question would be, on the component that is redirect, why redirect instead of displaying the `<LogIn>` component?

Comment: I personally don't like that approach because it means the URL will sometimes show a login page and other times the real contents of the page but I guess it's whatever you think looks better. I'm not sure what the best practices are either

Comment: _Any security or usability problems?_ - you still should authorize user on API side, only that.

Comment: @SLCH000: yes, of course. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my first attempts to work with React, I too tried the approach of using a "controller component" of sort which would render the true component only if the user has logged in. It worked perfectly, The problems i faced were: 
 1. As the application became bigger, it was an extra step i had to add to each time.
 2. There are more effective solution.

I moved to react-router.  **React Router keeps your UI in sync with the URL**. It has a simple API with powerful features like **lazy code loading, dynamic route matching, and location transition handling built right in**.

They even have a off the shelf example for Protected Routing(Authentication)

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

The SPA can be made to follow the usual workflow that you have mentioned, when you access a URL.

Comment: I am using React Router. I'll check out documentation.